# Implementing PayPal PDT on behalf of others

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a site where my users can create invoices. I would like to offer my users the ability to have their invoices paid by their clients via PayPal. Each user on my site has their own paypal account.

I would like to use PDT so that the status of the invoice is updated to paid immediately after a payment is made via paypal. However, it would appear that this is not possible, because PDT requires that Auto Return is enabled (https://www.paypal.com/pdt) in the paypal account. Given that I don't have control of all my clients' paypal accounts (and I can't ask all of them to enable Auto Return), this doesn't seem to be feasible.

However, looking further into Standard Payments (https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics), I can create a form variable called `return` (see Setting The Return URL on Individual Transactions). Does this mean that PDT data will be returned when using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  It is very similar to PDT except that it will be triggered regardless of whether Auto Return is enabled and whether or not the user actually makes it back to the site (which isn't guaranteed even with Auto-Return enabled).

The IPN system will POST transaction data to a listener on your web server in real-time.  This can be used to update your own database, send email notifications, hit 3rd party web services, or anything else you'd like to automate.

IPN happens "behind the scenes".  It's server-to-server communication, so it's not something that you'll see happening in the browser.  It will do exactly what you're wanting, though.